# Laravel Presence Channel: Store Joining and Leaving Users in database

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-7, pusher-js

I have this working:

```
Echo.join(`chat.${roomId}`)
    .here((users) => {
        //
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        this.users.push(user);
        this.saveStatus(user, 'online');
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        this.users = this.users.filter(u => u.id != user.id);
        this.saveStatus(user, 'offline');
   });
```

That shows me an accurate list of the Users that are present.
But what I want, is to store also their status in the database with a timestamp.

So I thought about this function:

```
saveStatus(user, status) {
   axios.post("/logbooks", { user_id: user.id, status: "offline"})
}
```

And call that function in the joining and leaving state. 
But that's not accurate: it doesn't store values when just one user is online. And when there are 20 users offline, and one user goes offline > it'll store 19 times this value.

Any tips how to get a more accurate online-offline-log to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Pusher Channels you can configure presence webhooks for your Channels app. You can activate webhooks in your [account dashboard](https://dashboard.pusher.com) on a per app basis.

The [presence webhook](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/webhooks#presence-events) will be triggered for the following events; member_added and member_removed (user joins a presence channel or user leaves a presence channel (goes offline)):

You can listen for these events on your server and then update the user state depending on what events you are receiving.

If the user can join multiple rooms (channels) at once (e.g. room1, room2, room3) you may want to track whether the user is online or offline by having a user specific presence channel.

For example if the user was called 'Joe Bloggs' you would join a channel called joebloggs when first connecting to your Pusher app. (if the user joins this channel they are online, if the user leaves this channel they are offline)

Comment: Great! Thanks. Did not know about the webhooks :)

Answer (score -1):

You could resolve this issue by using Laravel Echo Server (instead of Pusher) and Redis. Here is the documentation:

https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server#presence-channels

Redis handles a publish/subscribe mechanism. Laravel Echo Server publishes each time someone joins/leaves a presence channel, and with an Artisan command, you can subscribe to Redis and react to the join/leave by notifying your database.

Comment: Incorrect. This Presence channel is working via Pusher now and Laravel Echo.

Comment: You wanted a tip to face your issue, I gave it that I use myself and I said you would need to replace Pusher by Laravel Echo Server. The fact you want to keep Pusher is personal and the downvote is not deserved.

Comment: That was not a tip, because I'm using Laravel Echo already and Pusher also handles joining and leaving. This is working already as mentioned in the initial post. I'm not the only one who downvoted I see.

Comment: "Laravel Echo Server" != "Laravel Echo", the first one is a server, the latter one is a client

Comment: It does the same. No difference in Joining and Leaving events in Echo Server and Pusher.

Comment: I read it because I mentioned you would need to replace your Pusher, just saying. Notice the "would", it's a suggestion, not an order.